# How to apply a function to each element of a matrix?

Tags: python, function, numpy, matrix

For each element of a Matrix I want to count the sum of the k-closest cells.
From this function

```
def sum_neighbors(a, radius, row_number, column_number):
    A = [[a[i][j] if  i >= 0 and i < len(a) and j >= 0 and j < len(a[0]) else 0
                for j in range(column_number-1-radius, column_number+radius)]
                    for i in range(row_number-1-radius, row_number+radius)]
    return np.sum(A)
```

I can do this. For instance, If I have the following matrix

```
A
array([[1, 8, 2, 2, 8, 2, 4, 2, 6],
       [3, 6, 9, 9, 1, 8, 0, 3, 9],
       [7, 4, 2, 7, 8, 5, 8, 8, 1],
       [8, 3, 2, 3, 6, 9, 9, 1, 6],
       [1, 1, 3, 5, 6, 2, 9, 1, 8],
       [7, 0, 8, 7, 9, 8, 4, 4, 6],
       [1, 8, 5, 4, 7, 4, 8, 7, 0],
       [2, 8, 0, 3, 5, 6, 4, 3, 9],
       [1, 5, 1, 9, 9, 4, 5, 7, 9]])
```

I can run the following to get, for each values, the sum of the all the values a radius of 2 cells.

```
s = np.shape(A)
As = np.zeros(s)
for i in range(0,s[0]):
    for j in range(0,s[1]):
        As[i][j]=neighbors(A, 2, i, j)

As
array([[ 18.,  29.,  40.,  49.,  55.,  45.,  39.,  43.,  34.],
       [ 29.,  42.,  60.,  77.,  81.,  75.,  75.,  73.,  56.],
       [ 40.,  55.,  76.,  99., 104., 104., 103., 104.,  81.],
       [ 42.,  60.,  86., 115., 121., 129., 126., 130., 101.],
       [ 40.,  64.,  95., 125., 131., 147., 140., 139., 109.],
       [ 40.,  60.,  86., 122., 126., 148., 149., 144., 108.],
       [ 39.,  57.,  79., 112., 122., 136., 134., 141., 108.],
       [ 34.,  51.,  79., 115., 127., 135., 140., 144., 108.],
       [ 32.,  46.,  69.,  99., 110., 110., 117., 118.,  88.]])
```

However, for large matrices the loop takes infinite time. Is there a way to apply the function to each element of the matrix without a loop?

Comment: Either your results aren't correct, or your problem statement is unclear. The top left corner of your results look like the sum of radius 1, while the top right corner looks like the sum of radius 2.

Comment: @ddejohn the main question is how to map the function to each cell without a loop.

Comment: Looks like a full convolution with an offset: `scipy.signal.convolve2d(A, np.ones((radius*2+1, radius*2+1)), 'full')[1:10,1:10]`

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny yes I wanted to solve as a convolution but I have issues on the borders.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny maybe we can solve in this way `scipy.signal.convolve2d(A, np.ones((radius*k+1, radius*k+1)), mode='same', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)[1:10,1:10]`

Comment: Were you helped by my answer? Please consider accepting it if so, or update your question if not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

The way to deal with the border issue is to pad the array with `k` zeros. Since you are summing adding these values to your array has no effect -- it simply makes life easier. Consider the top-left corner of your original array:

```py
1 8 2 ...
3 6 9 ...
7 4 2 ...
.     .
.      .
.       .
```

You want to look a distance `k = 2` in every direction from the `1` there at the very corner, for instance. By padding `A` with `k = 2` zeros, we get

```
0 0 0 0 0 ...
0 0 0 0 0 ...
0 0 1 8 2 ...
0 0 3 6 9 ...
0 0 7 4 2 ...
.         .
.          .
.           .
```

The padding helps with the borders, but the trick to this process is taking advantage of numpy's `stride_tricks` sub-module. We are essentially performing a 2D convolution, and yes, you could use `scipy` for this, if you happen to have it installed and it's already a dependency on your project.

### Solution

```py
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as windows

k = 2  # radius; k >= 1
w = 2*k + 1  # window size; 1x1, 3x3, 5x5, ...

# A = np.array(...)  # from question
neighbor_sums = windows(np.pad(A, k), (w, w)).sum(axis=(2, 3))
```

Output for `k = 1`:

```py
array([[18, 29, 36, 31, 30, 23, 19, 24, 20],
       [29, 42, 49, 48, 50, 44, 40, 41, 29],
       [31, 44, 45, 47, 56, 54, 51, 45, 28],
       [24, 31, 30, 42, 51, 62, 52, 51, 25],
       [20, 33, 32, 49, 55, 62, 47, 48, 26],
       [18, 34, 41, 54, 52, 57, 47, 47, 26],
       [26, 39, 43, 48, 53, 55, 48, 45, 29],
       [25, 31, 43, 43, 51, 52, 48, 52, 35],
       [16, 17, 26, 27, 36, 33, 29, 37, 28]])
```

For `k = 2`:

```py
array([[ 42,  60,  77,  81,  75,  75,  73,  56,  41],
       [ 55,  76,  99, 104, 104, 103, 104,  81,  57],
       [ 60,  86, 115, 121, 129, 126, 130, 101,  75],
       [ 64,  95, 125, 131, 147, 140, 139, 109,  77],
       [ 60,  86, 122, 126, 148, 149, 144, 108,  80],
       [ 57,  79, 112, 122, 136, 134, 141, 108,  79],
       [ 51,  79, 115, 127, 135, 140, 144, 108,  84],
       [ 46,  69,  99, 110, 110, 117, 118,  88,  66],
       [ 31,  47,  68,  78,  74,  85,  87,  66,  52]])
```

### With `scipy`

If you're already using scipy as a dependency in your project, you may as well take advantage of its specialized `convolve2d()` function:

```py
k = 2  # radius; k >= 1
w = 2*k + 1  # window size; 1x1, 3x3, 5x5, ...

neighbor_sums = scipy.signal.convolve2d(A, np.ones((w, w), int), mode='same')
```

### Performance

A quick benchmark shows that scipy's `convolve2D()` function is indeed faster:

```py
In [18]: ones = np.ones((w, w), int)

In [19]: padded_A = np.pad(A, k)

In [20]: %timeit convolve2d(A, ones, mode='same')
9.79 µs ± 786 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [21]: %timeit windows(padded_A, (w, w)).sum(axis=(2, 3))
34.5 µs ± 6.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: how did you define `windows`?

Comment: My bad, edited.

Comment: it does not seem to work for k=2

Comment: Please clarify what "does not seem to work" means. How are you determining if a given result is correct? To what are you comparing my results? As I mentioned in another comment, either the expected output you posted in your question is incorrectly calculated, or it isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Upvote for a very neat answer to a problem that many stumble upon while dealing with convolutions.